# Experience system for an rpg in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a decent way to implement an experience system with the following requirements:

- Ability to handle different kinds of experience gain (for characters, weapons, skills/spells, etc)
- Flexible enough to allow for additions of different kinds of experience types
- Capable of granting appropriate rewards / bonuses for levels gained

Is there a design pattern that would fit something like this, so I don't have to go and reinvent the wheel? Or should I just go ahead and try to come up with something from scratch with some potential suggestions from y'all?

Edit: I've thought of using an Interface called ILevelable and having that be the base for the classes to build off of, but I can't help but feel that I'll have to have more specific Interfaces for particular cases - or could the one ILevelable interface be enough across all of its requirements?

```
interface ILevelable
    {
        int Level { get; set; }
        int CurrentExp { get; set; }
        int ExpToNextLevel { get; set; }

        void GainExp(int xp); // This may return a bool at some point - depends on design
        int CalculateNextLevel(); // Will be used to determine what the next level-up exp amount will be
        int LevelUp(); // Returns the current new level - this could be where rewards are granted?
    }
```

Comment: Your use-case is too specific for there to be something built-in in C#. That doesn't meant you will have to make your own from scratch, however, as there will probably be stuff like that in game-specific asset stores... For a price.

Comment: What do you mean design pattern not to reinvent the wheel: You still have to implement the pattern. Do you have any code and a specific issue you need help with?

Comment: @AlmightyR - sorry, I didn't mean for there to be something built-in, in C# - I only mentioned C# so if someone gave some sort of example, that they might give it in C# syntax (not that it would be that huge of a deal if it was in their preferred language). I know there isn't already an "Experience" object, or some already built-in library for it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi The issue at hand is that I'm not sure if there's an existing pattern that could help me implement something like this. Like how the Singleton pattern would be good for something like an ObjectManager or a Logger.

Comment: Yes there may be a pattern but your requirement are too high level to determine a design pattern from it. And it is too specific. How about you come up with a design and then see if there is some pattern which will help in certain situations. At this point, I doubt anyone here will be able to suggest a pattern. Best if you get to work and not waste your time. Design patterns are overrated especially when chosen prematurely.

Comment: @GrowingCode247 I just posted what I think is a reasonable approach to address all requirements. Turn my *"C# from memory"* into actual C#, modify and adapt as necessary to your own needs, and you're good to go. Probably... =)

Comment: @CodingYoshi - yeah I figured it would be better to just go at it. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @AlmightyR - this seems like it could be something that'd work. I'm going to try messing around with a few things. Might DM if I get something tangible and thank you directly (+ upvote!) if it ends up spawning directly from or gained inspiration from your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean by *"handle"*, but I think a `Dictionary<enum, delegate>` approach, where the `enum` is an index of types of experience, and the `delegate` is responsible for handling each type, should work for those requirements.

---

Example in the *"C# from memory"* programming language, that should be considered C#-like pseudocode (just because I don't have my IDE open and won't bother right now):

```
//XP types
enum ExperienceType {
    Character, Weapon, Skill, Spell, Programming
}

//Maps types to handlings...
//You can map different types to different behaviors (requirement #1)
//You can map as many types and/to as many behaviors as you want (requirement #2)
//You can handle rewards in the delegates (requirement #3)
Dictionary<ExperienceType, Action<double>> handlers = /*...*/;

//Handle XP gained according to type; handler takes care of different behaviour
public void EarnXP(double amount, ExperienceType type){
    //handlers[type] gets delegate from dictionary
    //(amount) invokes the acquired delegate using amount as parameter
    handlers[type](amount);

    //delegate is responsible for handling what to do...
    //So you can effectively have a different handler (method) for each XP type
    //While the addition of more XP is a "simple" EarnXP(amount, type)
}
```

Comment: Ain't it cool when you get downvoted without explanation on an answer the OP stated can be useful? 